# License for an Internet radio with User feedback

Tags: internet, intellectual-property, licensing

I'd like to start an internet radio station app. The station will collect feedback, like thumbs-up and thumbs-down, from listeners in order to select the best songs to play next. The algorithm will be complex and will play a great diversity of songs and artists -- users arent directly picking songs, rather it's partly random and partly based on feedback.

BMI, ASCAP, and SoundExchange all include clauses saying that a user is not allowed to select the next song. I've also read that radio stations arent allowed to take feedback at all -- that communication should be one way. But some radio stations take in calls from users for song requests? And they must receive feedback somehow to know if they're giving users what they want?

Would this type of feedback be allowed under these licenses?